# How do you get Django's filer app to list new files at the top of the list?

Tags: python, django, file, upload

We are using the django filer app (version 0.9.5, http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to manage our file uploads.  Works very nicely, but when you upload new files they always appear at the bottom of the list, so inevitably we have to scroll all the way to the bottom through huge lists of files to find what we just uploaded.  We would like to have newly uploaded files appear at the top instead.

I've moved filer to our apps directory, so it can be modified.  Thus far, I've attempted changing the ordering (line 313 of /admin/folderadmin.py).  Changing the order by clause to use "-modified_at" breaks the ordering functionality.  Now I'm looking at changing the save method of the file model (in /models/filemodels.py) to include something like the following:

```
...
if not self.id:
    try:
        folder = self.folder if self.folder else None
        order_first = self.__class__.objects.filter(folder=folder).aggregate(
            models.Min('order'))['order__min'] - 1
        if order_first <= 1:
            self.__class__.objects.filter(folder=folder).update(
                order=models.F('order') + 1000)
                self.order = 1000 + order_first
            else:
                self.order = order_first
        except (TypeError, IndexError):
            pass
    super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Idea here is to assign the most recently uploaded item an order just previous to the topmost item in the current folder, so that it appears first in the list.  Unfortunately, save is used in more ways than I am aware of, and this is not working presently.  Any ideas on how we might do something like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution that works for this.  On line 313 of /admin/folderadmin.py is the following line:

```
file_qs = file_qs.order_by('order')
```

Change this to:

```
file_qs = file_qs.order_by('-order')
```

This reverses the display order so that newest items appear first in the list.  Unfortunately, by itself it also breaks the ability to sort.  We have photo galleries where files need to appear in a specific order, so sorting is important.  To fix this, we would also need to make a change to the sorting view in /filer/views.py by replacing

```
for pk in request.POST.getlist('indexes'):
```

with

```
index_list = request.POST.getlist('indexes')
index_list.reverse()
for pk in index_list:
```

When new indices are submitted, the filer does not know that the entire contents of the directory have been intentionally reversed, so unless we reverse this list, the entire contents of the directory will be flip-flopped every time we move things around.  Reversing the index list accommodates the change we've made to display order.

Think this covers it, but if anyone knows of any instances where this breaks something else unintentionally, please leave a comment.

Comment: Changing the filer source (as for any third-party source) is really not ok at all. You lose the ability to easily upgrade the code. NO GOOD.